# Run py.test for single function from context menu

Tags: pycharm, pytest

Using the Unittest framework in PyCharm (2017.1) I can do a right click on a function inside a test case and select `Run Unittest for ...`:

[image]

For a different project I am using `py.test` and this entry in the context menu does not exist any more.

Is it possible to achieve the same with `py.test` without having to set up a dedicated run configuration for each test case?

Comment: Upgrade to PyCharm 2017.1.2 -- they continue fixing bugs with test usability. 2017.1.2 (released today), has even more fixes for the tests. At least, it fixed issues for me and pytest.

Comment: That has not been fixed...

Comment: Did you delete your all previous custom configurations and set pytest as default test runner after the upgrade?

Comment: Im bit late, this might help . You need to change the setting , go to settings-->python integrated tool --> default test-runner. change it to py.test. You will see it appear as option Run py.test

Comment: It will work, but then you have to right click the test script file name in the Project window. If you right click the file editor area of the same test script instead, it still shows the old default tool (Unittests) unfortunately. This is annoying as I can't specify the individual function that I want to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue as been fixed in one of the recent updates of pycharm. 
I am using now 2017.2.3 and it behaves as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had this, and invalidating the cache or restarting PycCharm did nothing. Created a new function at the top of the file:

```
def test_dummy(): pass
```

Then PyCharm (2017.2.3) realised the file was tests, and allowed me to run py.test on my test classes and their test_* methods from the context menu.

It's an untidy work-around, but it may help.

If I remove the dummy test function, that file only gets option to Run, not py.test.

Some of my Python files are recognised as tests, some not. It's not obvious why.

It's annoying that there isn't a keyboard shortcut for run with default unit test runner that is distinct from just run. Both are Ctrl+shift+R.